# How can I define a constant for model and view in Django

Tags: python, django, view, model, constants

How can I define a constant so it would be available in views.py and models.py?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put it in `const.py` and import it in view as well as model.

Answer (score 0):

It's very likely that views.py will import models.py, so normally it's recommended to put in models.py constants and any other code to be used from views.py, forms.py or any other module inside your app.